# What is the difference between "system/subsystem" and "software" in a SSS vs SRS?

Tags: requirements, specifications

What is the difference between a System/Subsystem Specification (SSS) and a Software Requirements Specification (SRS)? I am struggling to find a precise definition between System/Subsystem and Software. I know that the SRS is more detailed than the SSS in that it includes mentions of interface of how it interacts with other software and hardware. However,I still can't make the connection of how the SRS relates back to the SSS.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the System which is specified by SSS is composed of only one Software component but nothing else. That is no hardware component exist and it is hardware agnostic. In this case SSS is equivalent to SRS.

If, however, other components (desktop computer, controller, motor etc.) exist then SRS consist of requirements which are subset of SSS requirements (mapped to the software component). Furthermore, SRS may contain some derived requirements that may arise during mapping process.

Answer (score -1):

A SSS specifies something with at least one atom in it. A SRS specifies something with no atoms in it, but, specifically a set of instructions intended to be executed by a processor.

Comment: In what context are you referring an "atom" to?